# Global sorting in tandem with jPaginate breaks Next/Previous buttons

Tags: jquery, sorting, pagination, global

I cannot seem to get jPaginate (http://web.enavu.com/js/jquery/jpaginate-jquery-pagination-system-plugin/) to play nicely with a sorting plugin I got from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/sorting-values-with-javascript/. I've been banging my head for hours. The issue is that if I want to sort items I have to show all items, remove my pagination ul, and reinstantiate jPaginate so that page 1 shows the first 16 *globally sorted* items, page 2 shows the second 16 sorted items, etc. Otherwise I get items 1-16 sorted within themselves on page 1, then items 17-32 sorted within themselves on page 2, etc. Unfortunately, if I reinstantiate jPaginate, the Next and Previous buttons no longer always work.

The page in question is http://www.alkemiejewelry.com/collections/bangles and I've created a simplified jsfiddle copy at http://jsfiddle.net/TDBSB/3/. Try clicking "Price" to sort by Price and then click "Next". Notice how everything disappears.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the paginate-plugin for jquery, but it looks a bit odd to use this plugin on the same set of elements multiple times. Maybe you should check if there is a way to remove the paginate plugin from the element and add it again after sorting it.

I do ,however, find it quite weird to do this kind of sorting on the client-side. How will the plugin hold up when you have more and more items(say like a couple of hundred)? I would do this kind of stuff server-side using a simple sort on the database.

Comment: That's what I'm doing--removing the paginate plugin, sorting the items, then adding it again. The problem is after that operation the paginate plugin breaks for some unknown reason. I can't do this on the server side because we're using Shopify and Shopify limits output to 50 products for certain operations. I was considering the jquery tablesorter plugin, but I need to apply the sorting to floated boxes not rows, and so I think that would force invalid code.